# List Threshold persists even after filtering

Tags: 2010, list-view-threshold

I have a List which had columns indexed.

The list exceeded 5000 items. Now it is not allowing to add new item displaying error:

> This view cannot be displayed because it exceeds the list view threshold (5000 items) enforced by the administrator.

Now I applied filter to the view and still the error is thrown. The column on which filer is applied is indexed (Modified by).

I even filtered to show only one entry still error persists.

Only option left is to increase threshold through admin but don't want the performance issue.

Any idea why even after filtering the error exists.

Answer (score 1):

So, you can view the list, but it errors when you click to add a new item? Or, does the error come up after clicking to save the new item?

Does your list have any lookup fields? A lookup field that references a list that contains more than 5000 items will also throw a list threshold error.

Comment: Yes. Error when adding new item. List has lookup to another List reaching its threshold(4900). Any way to solve the error